how to start page number from second page?
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const hbs = require('handlebars');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const data = require('./data.json');
const ThermalPrinterHelper = require('./ThermalPrinterHelper');
const { generateQrCode, generateBarCode } = require('./generator');

hbs.registerHelper('inc', function (value, options) {
    return parseInt(value) + 1;
});

// Function to compile Handlebars template
const compile = async function (template, data) {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'templates', `${template}.hbs`);
    const templateSource = await fs.promises.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8');
    return hbs.compile(templateSource)(data);
};

const styleContent = `
            <style>
                .invoice-code {
                    display: flex;
                    justify-content: space-between;
                    align-items: center;
                    width: 100%;
                    min-height: 100px;
                    font-size: 10px;
                }
            </style>
        `;

function groupBySubtotalQuantity(poItems) {
    const groupedPayload = {};
    poItems.forEach((item) => {
        const groupKey = item.article_no.toString().substring(0, 9); // Get the first 4 characters of article_no
        const totalQuantity = parseFloat(item.quantity); // Convert quantity to a floating-point number
        if (!groupedPayload[groupKey]) {
            groupedPayload[groupKey] = {
                total_quantity: 0, // Initialize total quantity to 0
                items: [],
            };
        }
        groupedPayload[groupKey].items.push(item);
        groupedPayload[groupKey].total_quantity += totalQuantity; // Add quantity to total quantity
    });

    // Format total_quantity to have up to 3 decimal places and convert to string
    Object.keys(groupedPayload).forEach((key) => {
        groupedPayload[key].total_quantity = parseFloat(
            groupedPayload[key].total_quantity.toFixed(3)
        ).toFixed(3);
    });

    // Sort items within each group based on the last number of the material description
    Object.keys(groupedPayload).forEach((key) => {
        groupedPayload[key].items.sort((a, b) => {
            const getLastNumber = (str) => parseInt(str.match(/\d+$/)[0]); // Extract last number from string
            return (
                getLastNumber(a.material_description) -
                getLastNumber(b.material_description)
            );
        });
    });

    const result = Object.keys(groupedPayload).map((key) => groupedPayload[key]);

    return { po_item: result };
}

// Function to generate PDF
const generatePDF = async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: ['--no-sandbox'],
            devtools: true,
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        const payloadJSON = data;
        const groupedPayload = groupBySubtotalQuantity(payloadJSON.po_item);
        payloadJSON.po_item = groupedPayload.po_item;

        // Compile template with user and seller information
        const content = await compile('index', payloadJSON);

        const barcodeMarkup = await generateBarCode({ value: '123456789' });

        // Add the formatted text and barcode to your content
        const modifiedContent = content;

        await page.setContent(modifiedContent);

        await page.addStyleTag({
            content: `
                body { margin-top: 1cm; }
                @page:first { margin-top: 0; }
            `,
        });

        // Generate PDF for each page
        await page.pdf({
            path: 'output.pdf',
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true,
            preferCSSPageSize: true,
            displayHeaderFooter: true,
            margin: {
                top: '100px',
            },
            headerTemplate: `
                ${styleContent}
                <div class='invoice-code'>
                    <div style='width:40%; font-size: 10px;'></div>
                    <div style='width:30%; font-size: 10pt; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;'>PURCHASE ORDER</div>
                    <div style='width:30%; font-size: 10px; line-height:1.2;'>
                        <div style=' font-size: 10pt; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;'>Number<span style="font-weight: normal;"> : ${payloadJSON.po_number}</span></div>
                        <div style=' font-size: 10pt; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;'>Po Date<span style="font-weight: normal;"> : ${payloadJSON.po_date}</span></div>
                        <div style=' font-size: 10pt; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;'>Page No <span style="font-weight: normal;">:</span> <span style="font-weight: normal;" class="pageNumber"> </span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `,
            footerTemplate: `
                ${styleContent}
                <div class='invoice-code'>
                <div style='width:40%; font-size: 12px;'></div>
                </div>
            `,
        });

        console.log('PDF generated successfully');
        // await browser.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};

// Call the function to generate PDF
generatePDF();

I've tried tons of options to start the page number of the pdf from 0. Options which I tried using addScriptTag, evaluate method of the page, adding script tag to modify the pageNumber class, handling that too using CSS, doing -1 i know it's lame but I tried, read 15-20 blogs and forum regarding the issue nothing found helpful and failed in all the attempts. I am using puppeteer to generate PDF and it based on Chromium engine which starts page number from 1 and I want to start the page number from 0 and it has built-in class pageNumber which is nearly impossible to edit. How to do it? Else we can start page number from the second page onwards as the first page is cover and I am hiding the headerTemplate using css.
I want a single output pdf where the page number should start from the second page of the as the first page is cover page.

Please share a runnable, complete [mcve]. Right now, there are all sorts of undefined imports, particularly data, so this isn't in a state where it's easy to help with. Start by defining your problem before discussing the attempted solution, rather than the other way around. Mentioning you looked at 15-20 blogs doesn't do a lot of good unless you describe exactly what you tried from those blogs, or at least provide links to them. The point of asking "what did you try?" isn't to prove you did work, but to show concrete, specific code attempts that help isolate the problem.  Thanks.

This is not a satisfactory answer, just an analysis.
The headerTemplate and footerTemplate options of puppeteer's page.pdf() method are passed to Chromium's "Save as PDF" method. This method allows injection of a just few variables, in the Javascript function setupHeaderFooterTemplate here. For example, the element <span class="pageNumber"></span> in the template will have the current page number options.pageNumber injected.
What Chromium considers the "current page number" is defined in the C++ code here. I can imagine configuration options a user might want (start numbering from 0, or have 10 frontmatter pages numbered in roman numerals i, ii, ..., ix, x and then start numbering from 1, or ...). But Chromium does not offer such flexibility.
Note also that the Chromium C++ code must explicitly invoke the Javascript function kPageSetupScriptFormat = "setupHeaderFooterTemplate". Adding your own Javascript to the headerTemplate or footerTemplate therefore has no effect, it will simply not be executed.
If you want to deviate from these page numbering rules, you should define your own rules on the HTML document before PDF conversion. Use the CSS concepts @page and counter().
